# How to extract data from from top level Element Tree XML elements?

Tags: python, xml

I am learning XML element tree for python. I have successfully taken a XML response from an API for my own needs and parsed over it using this guide I found online. https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/parse.html

My example XML looks like this with NO child objects in the call:

```
<Response>
<Title>Student</Title>
<Date>7/18/2017 10:04:45 AM</Date>
<Description>Removed from group</Description>
</Response>
```

According to the article the article I iterated through the response like below to extract tag and attributes in Element Tree:

```
tree = et.fromstring(xml_response)

for node in tree.iter('Group'):
    print node.tag, node.attrib
```

This made all the XML elements become empty dictionary items(i think) and this was displayed like such:

```
Title{}
Date{}
Description{}
```

Now I wanted to grab the data in each of the calls and this was my attempt:

```
for node in tree.iter('Title'):
    Title = node.attrib.get('Title')
    print Title
```

The output I get is "None" from the above code. My question is what happened to the databetween the XML tags and how can I access the data?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your code look like? What does the source data look like?

Comment: @larsks just made a edit thank you!

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That means code that we can copy and run locally that demonstrates the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @larsks rewrote my question. Hope it makes sense now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
print node.tag, node.text
```

instead of

```
print node.tag, node.attrib
```

For xml line `<Date a="b">7/18/2017 10:04:45 AM</Date>` 
`node.attrib` will output `{'a':'b'}` 
`node.text` will output `'7/18/2017 10:04:45 AM'`

Comment: Holy crap that worked beautifully! thank you so much!